# How to use Vuetify 3 components in an own programmatically called component, e.g. open a dialog?

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I want to call a custom dialog with `this.$dialog.open('some message')`

My own dialog component uses some vuetify components.

I always got the error `Error: [Vuetify] Could not find defaults instance`

Did somebody has an example how to define a component, that it could use vuetify?

This is what i try (shortened version):

main (without imports, etc.)

```
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(createVuetify())
app.use(dialog)
```

dialog

```
export default {
  install: (app) => {
    const instance = createInstance()
    app.config.globalProperties.$dialog = instance
    app.provide('$dialog', instance)
  },
}

function createInstance() {
  return {
    open(message) {
      const instance = createComponent(Dialog, { message }, document.body)
      return {
        dismiss: instance.ctx.dismiss
      }
    }
  }
}

function createComponent(component, props, parent, slots = {}) {
  const vNode = h(component, props, slots)
  render(vNode, parent)
  return vNode.component
}
```

dialog.vue

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent width="auto">
    <v-card>
      {{ message }}
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Dialog',
  props: {
    message: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  data: () => ({ dialog: true }),
  methods: {
    dismiss() {},
  },
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Only the VNode you create in your `createComponent()` function is not registered to the current app, so it does not have access to the Vuetify components (or any data from app). To give it access, you can register the app in the VNode, all you have to do is to pass the app to `createComponent()` and then set the `appContext` property:

```
vNode.appContext = app._context
```

all in all, this gives you:

```
function createComponent(app, component, props, parent, slots = {}) {
  const vNode = h(component, props, slots)
  vNode.appContext = app._context
  render(vNode, parent)
  return vNode.component
}
```

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref, defineComponent, h, render } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const App = {
  inject:['$dialog'],
  methods: {
    showDialog(){
      console.log(this)
      this.$dialog.open('go go go')
    }
  }
}

const Dialog = {
  template: `
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent width="auto">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text>{{ message }}</v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
  `,
  name: 'Dialog',
  props: {
    message: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  data: () => ({ dialog: true }),
  methods: {
    dismiss() {},
  },
}

const dialog = {
  install: (app) => {
    const instance = createInstance(app)
    app.config.globalProperties.$dialog = instance
    app.provide('$dialog', instance)
  },
}

function createInstance(app) {
  return {
    open(message) {
      const instance = createComponent(app, Dialog, { message }, document.body)
      return {
        dismiss: instance.ctx.dismiss
      }
    }
  }
}

function createComponent(app, component, props, parent, slots = {}) {
  const vNode = h(component, props, slots)
  vNode.appContext = app._context
  render(vNode, parent)
  return vNode.component
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(vuetify)
app.use(dialog)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-btn @click="showDialog">Show</v-btn>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OMG, that is absolutely awesome! Thank you so much!  
I banged my head yesterday and thought how i could get context, but i did not see the tree in all the woods.